# How to adjust Button image and Button size from iphone 6 to iphone 6+

Tags: ios, xcode8

newbie here.

I started with iphone 6 for my app.
Say I have a button with fixed size w: 60 and h: 60 and I have a background image for the button : btnImage@2x.png, btnImage@3x and I dont have btnImage@1x.png ( if needed, can use btnImage.png or btnImage@1x.png ?) The size of the image is : 120x120.

In Design view for iphone6. It looks good.

Problem:
1. When viewing in iphone 6+ ( or iphone 7+) in Design view or storyBoard, The Image for the btn look small inside the button? I have btnImage@3x.png ,why it did not scale up with @3x image?

What I must do when change from iphone 6 to iphone 6+?

--UPdate

Button has two properties : 1) Image  2) Background 
using (1) will not scale up 
using (2) , it will scale.

Which one is the proper one?

Please help. Thanks

Comment: By the way, Is iphone 6 sae as iphone 7? If they are, how come the iphone 6 simulator is much smaller than iphone 7 simulator? and there is only iphone 7 as the default size for development? How to get iphone 6 screen in StoryBoard?

Comment: You can change the device view from the storyboard itself. bottom bar. if you cant see it properly try to only open the storybopard alone without the assistant editor.

Answer (score 0):

As much as I know the UIButton background image doesnot get scaled. Unless its bigger than the button size resolution.

> I guess that a more proper way to do this. Is to add a UIImageView
>   behind your button and set the image to it.

Alternativly, try the content alignment:

```
button.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentFill
button.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentFill
```

This also can be found on storyboard.